# Why does this datasheet report negative values for the gate threshold voltage?

Tags: mosfet

I am a bit surprised to find negative values for the gate threshold voltage in the datasheet of an n-channel MOSFET, reference [BSS159N from Infineon](https://4donline.ihs.com/images/VipMasterIC/IC/INFN/INFNS19227/INFNS19227-1.pdf?hkey=6D3A4C79FDBF58556ACFDE234799DDF0).

[image]

Since it is an n-channel, I would expect positive values instead. What am I missing?

Comment: That is a depletion mode MOSFET. Infineon has a guide to it. https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/power/mosfet/n-channel-depletion-mode/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a depletion-mode FET, which means it's "on" at Vgs=0, and you can turn it off by driving Vgs negative (below the threshold voltage). However, it does conduct *more* when Vgs becomes positive.

Pay attention to datasheet figure 7 (which shows turnoff below -2.x Vgs) and figures 5 and 6 (which show the neat "constant current" characteristic over a range of Vgs values).